Why is Navbar component from react-bootstrap not being imported in my NextJS App?
I am currently building a project on next@15.0.4 app, with react v 18.3.1. I have installed react-bootstrap 2.10.6 and bootstrap 5.3. However, I am running into a problem where using Navbar component is giving this error:
[ Server ] React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I have confirmed that react-bootstrap is otherwise properly functional and everything is properly imported. The versions are compatible. The only problem lies with the Navbar component, which is not being imported.
Can anyone tell me what the issue is, and how I can solve it?
I have confirmed that Boostrap is otherwise functional by running this code on page.js of my next app:
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="primary">Test React-Bootstrap</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

It worked perfectly. I also confirmed through console.log(Navbar) on the component/Header.js page that Navbar is not being imported. It rendered as "null".
I am expecting it to work just as well as it did in another React project where it worked perfectly, but that has not happened. Just to reiterate, the same code has worked perfectly in a previous react project. This is a NextJS issue with that particular component.

I was unable to move to Next 15 with my react-bootstrap project due to this react-bootstrap issue, which if I understand correctly, has to do with Next 15 using some/all React 19 under the hood. Do you get the same error on Next 14? I'm assuming your failing code is similar to what you showed as evidence of other components working, like:
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

